# Xamarin Page Not Being Updated After Initialization

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

Hi I'm relatively new to xamarin, I'm facing an issue with my Xamarin.iOS project, the content page is not being updated for some reason I am not aware of, its a little confusing for me at least. There's a logo thats retrieved and a value thats calculated via a call to a web api on our server, none are displayed just blank a content page. I tried to debug the error by placing a breakpoint in the method that retrieves the image and value calculated on the web api server, and upon doing so, I see this message in the Application Output Window.

```
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
```

The weird thing I noticed though is that if I don't add a breakpoint the application continues to run without throwing any exception or crashing, but there's no point in that because all I'm faced with is no data and a blank ui.

Here's the method I'm using to retrieve data:

```
public async void LoadCards()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Requests.Cards> cd = new List<Requests.Cards>();
            var content = "";
            var RestUrl = Settings.RestUrl + "/api/Customer/GetCustomerCards?CustomerID=" + Helpers.Settings.storecustID;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Giftworx-App", Helpers.Settings.Usertoken);

            if (Helpers.Settings.Usertoken == string.Empty || Helpers.Settings.storecustID == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl);


            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Requests.Cards>>(content);

            CardBalance.ItemsSource = Items;

            foreach (var i in Items)
            {
                StorePic.Source = i.CustomerLogo;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Here's the Xaml Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.TabbedPages.Abraham">
    <ContentPage.Content>
          <Grid>
    <Image Source="NewBg.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                     Padding="10, 10, 5, 10">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <Image HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="StorePic"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView HeightRequest="5" />

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#33ffffff">
            <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       >
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="10" />
                    <Label
                                Text="LOYALTY CARD BALANCE"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="White"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                    <ListView x:Name="CardBalance" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="CardBalance_Refreshing" ItemTapped="CardBalance_ItemTapped" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 x:Name="Layout"
                                            
                                        >
                                        <Label
                                Text="{Binding Balance, StringFormat='{0:N2}'}}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="40"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="White"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="25">
                                                <Image Source="point.png" WidthRequest="19" HeightRequest="19" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="20">
                                                <Label Text="Tap to view detail" TextColor="White" FontSize="12"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
  
        <BoxView HeightRequest="5" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Text="PROMOTIONS" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="300" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" BorderRadius="40" BackgroundColor="#1Affffff" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="TRANSACTIONS" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="300" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" BorderRadius="30" BackgroundColor="#1Affffff" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>
                    <Button Text="RECEIPTS" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="300" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" BorderRadius="30" BackgroundColor="#1Affffff" IsVisible="false"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="40" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: relevant code posted

Comment: this appears to be Xamarin Forms, not X.iOS.  Are you sure your data is getting loaded successfully and no exceptions are thrown?  What does the XAML or code for your ContentPage look like?

Comment: You are accessing UI controls. You probably don't access them from the UI thread. One can't tell from the code, but that would be the best guess.

Comment: @Jason I  posted the Xaml code. Ivan I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Jason There is no data being loaded when I place my breakpoint what I noticed is that, as mentioned previously, while stepping through the method, after three lines in I get the error message i posted above, but without the breakpoint there are no exceptions thrown

Comment: How do you know that?  You are just silently capturing any exceptions that do occur.  Try at least adding some writelines in your code so you can verify that each line is executed and what data is being returned.

Comment: Good point @Jason, but here's the thing take a look at this line of code `var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Requests.Cards>>(content);` if I put a break point there, in the application output window I get this message `Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Abraham.xaml.cs:47,1' to void LoyaltyWorx.TabbedPages.Abraham.<LoadCards>d__2.MoveNext () [0x001e7].` and it doesn't even hit

Comment: Have you even verified that your HTTPRequest is returning data?  If you're having trouble with the debugger, then try using debug writelines to verify your code instead.  Or try the usual things - restart your IDE, delete all bin/obj folders, remove app from sim, then do a clean build.

Comment: Okay I've tried all the suggestions listed above. Maybe this might help, I recently added a plugin called [PlatformTabbedPages](https://github.com/messier16/PlatformTabbedPage) and I had a look at the Application Output window, after that assembly is loaded, it seems that there are quite a few Threads being start and stopped : 
Check out this [https://pastebin.com/83pWGnHb](paste bin)

Comment: Have you tried debugging on the return `CardBalance.ItemsSource = Items` if there is a return?

Comment: @Swift_Talt Yes I tried that, it doesn't hit the breakpoint when I put it there

Answer (score 0):

Use BeginInvokeOnMainThread and call this in OnApearing method

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (LoadCards);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a problem with the query string in the url, the value weren't being taken from the right source so basically instead of :

`Settings.RestUrl + "/api/Customer/GetCustomerCards?CustomerID=" + Helpers.Settings.CustID;`

I had this this:

`Settings.RestUrl + "/api/Customer/GetCustomerCards?CustomerID=" + Helpers.Settings.storecustID;`

The reason why the breakpoints weren't hitting when I placed them deeper inside the method was because of the `if statement` with the return keyword, what still confuses me though is that while stepping through the method the app used to crash before I even managed to step into the `if statement`, which made it even more difficult to figure out what the initial cause of the problem was.

Comment: The app wouldn't show anything since you won't return anything and you have are using try catch (it really wouldn't crash, debug on your catch statement maybe you will see the error). Maybe you should instantiate your list and return it with nothing to return by default. Plus, if you meet the conditions of those inside of your if statement.